# how to replace certain elements in the pandas dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, indexing, replace

I have a dictionary and want to use .replace to only replace the indices that are in the dictionary key withe values.

```
dicts = {"certain index element1": "changed element1",
             "certain index element2": "changed element2",
             "certain index element3": "changed element3",
             }
```

This does not work:

```
df.replace(dicts,regex=False,inplace=True)
```

The `df` is huge so I can not reassign all of the index from scratch. I only need to change certain elements and everything else remains the same.

If I wanted to replace certain elements within the `df` (not indices) it would work but for indices it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rename(index=dicts)`

---

***example***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(list('abcd'), (10, 10)),
    list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
)
dc = {'A': '_A_', 'B': '_B_'}

df.rename(index=dc, inplace=True)

print(df)

     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
_A_  a  a  a  a  b  a  d  c  c  b
_B_  b  c  c  a  a  a  b  b  a  b
C    b  b  d  b  d  c  c  a  a  b
D    d  d  d  d  c  b  b  a  a  d
E    d  c  c  c  a  d  a  d  d  a
F    d  c  d  c  d  d  d  d  b  d
G    b  c  d  c  c  b  c  a  a  b
H    c  c  c  b  b  a  a  b  c  a
I    c  a  a  b  a  d  c  c  a  a
J    a  a  a  c  a  b  d  c  c  c
```